# How well MVC applications work on IIS < 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

So, I've managed to deploy an MVC application on IIS 5.1 on production. No problems so far.

The question is, is it actually fine to have it run like this? The way to deploy it felt so hacky, it feels it's hold on by a thread. Is this solution as stable and performant as it would be with a newer IIS?

Besides that more modern versions of IIS could be more perfect, are there any other reasons why an MVC application would not work so well on IIS < 7 ?

Comment: I've successfully deployed MVC to IIS 6 in the past with no problems.  I can't speak for anything older than that though.

Comment: IIS 5.1 on desktop is never considered to be a valid production environment, and of course both IIS 5.1 and 6 are dead.

Comment: @LexLi I understand, however, I had to. Now I'm looking for evidences

Comment: I think a lot of people will interested to know why you need to use a version of `IIS` that is no longer supported. I'd be surprised that many people will be able to answer your question regards IIS 5.1/6.0, only because IIS versions earlier than 8 are so out of date.

Comment: @JasonEvans Long story short: licensing.

Comment: You might want to look in getting a Shared Host, Virtual Private Server or host on Azure if pricing is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

IIS 5.1 has a [limit of 10 concurrent connections](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262635), and is not meant for production use. If you have more traffic than 10 users at the same time then clearly this version of IIS is not going to work.

It is possible to [increase this limit](http://blog.codinghorror.com/uncrippling-windows-xps-iis-51/), but as [XP support has been totally dropped](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help) you are swimming in dangerous waters. Since there are no more Windows Updates, your chances of getting hacked will increase over time as new vulnerabilities in XP are discovered and not patched.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How do you think IIS 6 will perform?

Comment: IIS 6 will perform better because it was meant for production use. But [support has also ended for Windows Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?alpha=Windows%20Server%202003%20R2), so the same issues with security still apply.